# how to format a decimal value in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
var data = (from objData in receiptData
            select new
            {
                ITEM_NAME=objData.ITEM_NAME,
                UNIT_NAME=objData.UNIT_NAME,
                PACK = objData.PACK,
                RECIEVED_QTY =objData.RECIEVED_QTY.Value.ToString("0"), // ***this statement invoke error***
                LPRATE = objData.LPRATE,
                AMT = objData.LPRATE.Value * objData.RECIEVED_QTY.Value,
                ESL = objData.ESL,
                REMARKS = objData.REMARKS,
                CHALLAN_NO=objData.CHALLAN_NO,
                VEH_NO=objData.VEH_NO
            });
```

Comment: What type of LINQ is this? EF? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Objects? (I suspect not the latter...)

Comment: What kind of error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
var data = (from objData in receiptData 
            select new 
            {
                ITEM_NAME=objData.ITEM_NAME,
                UNIT_NAME=objData.UNIT_NAME,
                PACK = objData.PACK,
                RECIEVED_QTY =objData.RECIEVED_QTY.Value.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                LPRATE = objData.LPRATE,
                AMT = objData.LPRATE.Value * objData.RECIEVED_QTY.Value,
                ESL = objData.ESL,
                REMARKS = objData.REMARKS,
                CHALLAN_NO=objData.CHALLAN_NO,
                VEH_NO=objData.VEH_NO
            });
```

Comment: `dataField.Value.ToString("#,###,##0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` Works in Linq to objects

Answer (score 1):

You should refer [Decimal.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for formatting decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Round(objData.RECIEVED_QTY.Value,2)
```